# Start coroutine on an inactive/de-activated GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following code:

```
void Start()
{
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
    StartCoroutine(Load());
}

IEnumerator Load()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
    gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

This gives me an error that says:

> Coroutine couldn't be started because the the game object 'NameOfObj'
>   is inactive!

This makes sense, since the game object has been set to deactivate before running the script. Even still, what is it that I'm supposed to do then? I tried moving `gameObject.SetActive(false)` to the coroutine, before `WaitForSeconds()`. Doing this stopped the game object from loading at all.

From my understanding, when the line `gameObject.SetActive(false)` is executed, the script stops running until the game object is reactivated. However, if this is the case, would it not be impossible to then reactivate the game object (as the script is disabled)?

Regardless, how would I delay my game object from loading until 2-3 (or any arbitrary length of time) after the game has started?

Comment: Move the script to a different game object and reference the object you want to activate?

Comment: Which function? `Load()`?

Comment: It'd be the same but just attached to a different empty gameobject. Then the game object you are deactivating is separate from the script so the script will keep running.

Comment: I have a lot of game object's though (that are the same); would this mean referencing all of them in this one game object or creating a separate game object for each one i want to delay?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot start a coroutine function from a script that has its GameObject de-activated.

The `StartCoroutine` function is a function under the `MonoBehaviour` class. When you have to start a coroutine on a deactivated GameObject, you need a reference to a `MonoBehaviour` object that has an active GameObject.

**Two ways to do this**:

**1**. Use an already existing GameObject that's unlikely to be deactivated. In my case, I usually use the camera. I access the camera's `MonoBehaviour` since it's likely to be activated then use it to start the coroutine function.

*I suggest you use  this method.*

Replace the code in your `Start` function with the one below:

```
//De-activate this GameObject
gameObject.SetActive(false);
//Get camera's MonoBehaviour
MonoBehaviour camMono = Camera.main.GetComponent<MonoBehaviour>();
//Use it to start your coroutine function
camMono.StartCoroutine(Load());
```

---

**2**. Attach the script to an empty GameObject and the script on the empty GameObject will control or be able to activate/de-activate the other GameObject.

The script with the coroutine function you expect to run on a de-activated GameObject (Attach it to the GameObject you wish to de-activate):

```
public class YourDeactivatableScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    public IEnumerator Load()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Now, let's say that you want to deactivate a GameObject named *"Cube"* that has the `YourDeactivatableScript` script attached to it but still be able to start its `Load` coroutine function, create an empty GameObject with a new script, then start the Load function from it.

Create an empty GameObject then attach this script to it:

```
public class LoadFuncCallerScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject targetObject;

    public void Start()
    {
         //Find the GameObject you want to de-activate
        targetObject = GameObject.Find("Cube");
        //De-activate it
        targetObject.SetActive(false);
        //Get it's component/script
        YourDeactivatableScript script = targetObject.GetComponent<YourDeactivatableScript>();
        //Start coroutine on the other script with this MonoBehaviour
        StartCoroutine(script.Load());
    }
}
```

The coroutine is now started from another script named `LoadFuncCallerScript`.

Comment: Supposing I had multiple of these game objects, I could technically then control all of them from the camera (using different functions) right?

Comment: Yes, the camera's MonoBehaviour  should be able to control or start the many coroutines as you wish. If you de-activate the camera, you'll kill all the coroutines it started.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't do exactly this. I called a function in a script attached to the camera that referenced the game object similar to suggestion 2. I will accept this answer nonetheless as it did solve my problem

Comment: You don't have to attach anything to do camera. You can just get the main camera and use it's `MonoBehaviour` for starting and stopping coroutines like I did but use whichever method works for you.

Answer (score 5):

What I do to avoid stopping coroutine is have a game object that does not get deactivated.

```
public class CoroutineHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static CoroutineHandler instance = null;
    public static CoroutineHandler Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(instance == null)
            {
                GameObject inst = new GameObject("CoroutineHandler");
                DontDestroyOnLoad(inst);
                instance = inst.AddComponent<CoroutineHandler>();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use this for such coroutines by using `CoroutineHandler.Instance.StartCoroutine(RoutineMethodHere());`.

If you do not want something like this, since it can go wrong or cause leaks if not handled correctly, you can try using `Invoke("MethodName", delay);`

Comment: Invoke won't work in my case because I need to delay `OnMouseOver()`.

Comment: Then you can use the concept of having a separate game object/mono to handle coroutines. As long as you stop the coroutines IF they get destroyed or unloaded, then it should be fine

Comment: This works well for me. I had a coroutine inside a prefab which was always firing that error, and that did the trick for me.