# Change a value of 5 to 1 over exactly 600ms

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game object in unity, that has `scale.x = 5` and `scale.y = 5` (since I'm working in 2D, the `z` component is irrelevant). What would be the best way to decrease the 5 to 1 over exactly 600 milliseconds? I've seen answers using `time.deltaTime` to change values per unit time (e.g. every 0.1 seconds), but this would be too imprecise. This would effectively mean decreasing it by 2/3 every 100ms, making it look as if it was stuttering. Is there a way to do this such that the game object's scale smoothly goes from 5 to 1 in 600ms?

Edit: Used exactly the code from the linked duplicate. I tried using it like this:

```
bool isRunning;
void Start ()
    {
        isRunning = false;
        StartCoroutine(ScaleIn(5, 4, 0.6f));
    }

IEnumerator ScaleIn(float currentScale, float scaleLoss, float duration)
{
    if (isRunning == true)
    {
        yield break;
    }
    isRunning = true;
    float counter = 0f;
    float startScale = currentScale;
    float endScale = currentScale - scaleLoss;
    float newScale = currentScale;
    while (counter < duration)
    {

        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        if (counter < duration)
        {
            Debug.Log("condition met");
        }
        Debug.Log("Counter: " + counter);
        newScale = Mathf.Lerp(startScale, endScale, counter / duration);
        Debug.Log("Current Scale: " + newScale);

        yield return null;
    }
        gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(newScale, newScale, 0f);
}
```

`condition met` prints in the console every time i run it, but exactly once. The log is telling me that `newScale` is 4.866666... and only prints this once. Even without the final line, `newScale` does not seem to be changing past the first time when it becomes 4.866666...

Comment: With the edit, where and **how** did you call the ScaleIn function? Copy and show it

Comment: I called the `ScaleIn()` function in `Start()` (because it's a coroutine). I called it with the parameters: `StartCoroutine(ScaleIn(5,4,0.6f))`. Added the edit to the post as well

Comment: I copied your code directly from your question, got 1 as the last log on my side which is the expected value. Disable other GameObjects. Just have only the code in your question. Make sure to place is calling this function. Run it then scroll down to the end of the log, take a screenshot and post screenshot of the Console log.

Comment: I have another script attached to the game object that "delays" the game object loading in, such that it's `SetActive(false)` at the start and is only `SetActive(true)` after some time (using `WaitForSeconds()`). This also uses a coroutine. When i enable this script, that script works but not the scale one. Is it not possible to run two separate coroutines for two separate scripts for the same game object at the same time?

Comment: You're disabling the object causing coroutine to shut down. I answered this question yesterday. Use the camera's `MonoBehaviour` to start the coroutine. `camMono.StartCoroutine`. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52999629/3785314) for how to get `camMono` reference.