# Can't start coroutine on instantiated prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, when I click a button i'm calling a coroutine on a script thats on my player (an instantiated prefab that I renamed as soon as its instantiated) and he should attempt to attack.

The code is as follows:

```
  public void AttackMonster()
  {
     StartCoroutine(TryAttack());
  }

  IEnumerator TryAttack()
  {
     var attacker = references.GetComponent<References>()
       .selectedPlayer.GetComponent<CharacterTemplate>();
     var enemyName = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject
       .GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text;
     var enemy = GameObject.Find(enemyName);
     var speed = attacker.speed;
     var accuracy = attacker.accuracy;
     var strength = attacker.strength;
     var enemyDefense = enemy.GetComponent<EnemyInfo>().defense;

     for (int i = 0; i < speed; i++) 
     {           
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        var accuracyTry = Random.Range(1, 11); 
        if (accuracyTry >= accuracy)
        {
           FloatingMessage("Hit");
          if (Hit(strength, enemyDefense))
          {
             Debug.Log("Wound");
          } 
          else 
          {
             Debug.Log("No wound");
          }
     } 
     else 
     {
        FloatingMessage("Miss");
     }
 }
```

And I'm getting the error:

> Coroutine couldn't be started because the the game object 'Player_prefab' is inactive!

I did some Debug.Break to test if the instantiated player was inactive, but it wasn't. It seems like the buttons onClick() is calling this function from the prefab, and not the instance, or something.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start coroutine on an inactive/de-activated GameObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52999487/start-coroutine-on-an-inactive-de-activated-gameobject)

Comment: Since you're instantiating prefabs during gameplay (I assume), are you dynamically assigning the button's click handler to the instantiated prefab(s)?  You can't do that at design-time since the objects were created during run-time, so if you've dragged a reference to the prefab into your button's `onClick` handler, then that's why you're calling the method on the prefab and not on the instance.

Comment: I am pretty sure the problem is on you OnClick thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer! And it was thanks to your questions guys, so thanks. :)
The problem was indeed on my onClick. I was setting it through the inspector, so it was being called from the prefab, not the instances.

All I had to do was assign it in the script and actually reference the instance instead of the prefab. Easy peasy.

```
enemyButton1.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(selectedPlayer.GetComponent<PlayerAttack>().AttackMonster);
```